# How do I count emoji and symbols in a cell?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, emoji, formulas

What formula can I use to get a count of emoji and characters in a single cell?

For example, In cells, A1,A2 and A3:

```
✋️

??
```

Total Count of characters in each cell(**Desired Output**):

```
3

5

5
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The same formula you'd use to get a count of something else in a cell.

Answer (score 3):

For the given emojis, This will work well:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A13,".","."))
```

- MID/LEN considers each emoji as 2 separate characters.
- REGEX will consider them as one.
- But even REGEX will fail with a complex emoji like this:

## ‍‍‍

This contains a literal man emoji, a woman emoji,a girl emoji and a boy emoji-all joined by a ZeroWidthJoiner. You could even swap the boy for a another girl with this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("‍‍‍‍","","")
```

It'll become like this:

## ‍‍‍‍

Comment: is there a way of doing this so that we could feed the formula a list of emoji's as a look up. This would be for the case that I may not know what emoji's are in the set.

Comment: @NickDuddy Probably yes, but you need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTA(FILTER(
  SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","#$1"),"#"),
  SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","#$1"),"#")<>""
 ))`

Based on the answer by @I'-'I

Some emojis contain from multiple emojis joined by `char(8205)`:

‍‍‍‍‍

[image]

The result differs and depends on a browser you use.

I wonder, how do we count them?